# Using an '&' in a string in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

What is the purpose of the '&' in the string in this line?

```
exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
```

Likewise here:

```
fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
```

Comment: That's how you signal which character should be the keyboard shortcut for the action. e.g. `alt-F S` in most apps triggers the filemenu, and goes to the "S" option, which is generally "save", so you'd have `.addMenu('&File')` `&F` -> "alt-F"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` character has a special purpose if you use it in the text of a `QAction` object: If the QAction object is used in a tool button, the character directly after the `&` symbol can be used as a keyboard shortcut for that button (in combination with the alt-key).

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html (resp. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#QAction-2).